# How to create Emoji Custom keyBoard in ios (objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, unicode, keyboard, character, emoji

is this possible to create custom keyboard with emoji characters. if yes ,than how? or apple allow this custom keyboard in my app or not . any idea ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [Text, Web, and Editing Programming Guide for iOS"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH12-SW2)

> The UIKit framework includes support for custom input views and input accessory views. Your application can substitute its own input view for the system keyboard when users edit text or other forms of data in a view. For example, an application could use a custom input view to enter characters from a runic alphabet. You may also attach an input accessory view to the system keyboard or to a custom input view; this accessory view runs along the top of the main input view and can contain, for example, controls that affect the text in some way or labels that display some information about the text.

To get this feature if your application is using UITextView and UITextField objects for text editing, simply assign custom views to the inputView and inputAccessoryView properties. Those custom views are shown when the text object becomes first responder...

Comment: ok i got it.. but one more think is this apple allow to make custom keyboard. or how can i convert an image to unicode ...

Comment: yes apple allow to create custom keyboard and use image instead of unicode